# How to exclude a URL when usinf PCF SSO service with EnableOAuth2Sso annotation?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, single-sign-on, cloud-foundry

I am using Angular and Spring Boot to build a Single Page app with Rest API. Here is my configuration:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableOAuth2Sso
public class AppConfig extends SpringBootServletInitializer implements ApplicationContextAware  {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(AppConfig.class);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext appContext = SpringApplication.run(AppConfig.class);
        context = appContext;
    }

    @Configuration
    protected static class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http.authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/healthcheck", "/").permitAll()
                    .antMatchers("/api/**").authenticated()
                    .anyRequest().authenticated();
        }
    }

}
```

The SSO service I am using is provided by Pivotal Cloud Foundry[PCF]. Everything was fine before I included

> SecurityConfig

class. As soon as the app is loaded, user is redirected to the SSO login page and then redirected back to the app. But I need to exclude the "healthcheck" URL from authentication. That is why I included the SecurityConfig class. But now the SSO Authentication is not working at all. I could only reach /healthcheck.

I followed this example https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-boot-oauth2/

Can someone please let me know what is wrong with my code?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. I had to move my EnableOAuth2Sso to the WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter. Like this:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class AppConfig extends SpringBootServletInitializer implements ApplicationContextAware  {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(AppConfig.class);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext appContext = SpringApplication.run(AppConfig.class);
        context = appContext;
    }

    @Configuration
    @EnableOAuth2Sso
    protected static class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http.authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/healthcheck", "/").permitAll()
                    .antMatchers("/api/**").authenticated()
                    .anyRequest().authenticated();
        }
    }

}
```